# Delay on array update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am getting a little delay on array update. My front-end (React.js) gets access before the back-end (node.js) updates it. Here is my back-end code:

```
router.get("/images/files", (req, res, next) => {
  let links = [];
  fileSchema
    .find()
    .then(doc => {
      doc.map(data => {
        client.files.getEmbedLink(data.fileID).then(file => {
          links.push(file);
          return res.status(200).json({
            status: "success",
            message: "Links are ready!",
            links: links
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

As you can seeIi am pushing links inside another array but I don't know how to respond when the array is fully updated.

Comment: Send the response after doc.map function execution is done.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wait for all of the promises from your `getEmbedLink` calls to resolve before sending your response.

This should help:

```
router.get("/images/files", (req, res, next) => {
  fileSchema
    .find()
    .then(doc => {
      // Create an array of promises
      const promises = doc.map(data => {
        return client.files.getEmbedLink(data.fileID)
      });

      // Wait for all promises to resolve
      return Promise.all(promises)
    })
    .then(links => {
      // "links" will be an array of results
      res.status(200).json({
        status: "success",
        message: "Links are ready!",
        links: links
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Handle error
    });
});
```